# Get json data via ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

Hopefully this is a fairly easy question. Pardon my ignorance, but I am mostly a PHP/Zend developer, so i am struggling a little in C# and Visual Studio with a json/ajax issue.  Is there something obvious I am missing? Any help will be appreciated. Should I be looking at `List<>`?

Here is the error I receive when I fire the javascript ajax function:
"Unknown web method getwidgets."

I have a dataset in C#, that I run through a JSON converter method.  This works well and returns my data in a JSON string.

```
private widgetsBL widgetsBLObject = new widgetsBL();

[WebMethod]
public String getwidgets()
{
    DataSet results = new DataSet();
    results = widgetsBLObject.selectTheWidgets();

    string jsresults = MyClassLibrary.JqueryTools.GetJSONString(results.Tables[0]);
    return jsresults;
}
```

Here is the jsresults:

```
{"Table" : [  {"widgetid" : "1","widgetname" : "gizmo1000","widgetdescription" : "very cool widget"},
{"widgetid" : "2","widgetname" : "gizmo2000","widgetdescription" : "decent widget"},
{"widgetid" : "3","widgetname" : "gizmo3000","widgetdescription" : "terrible widget"}     ]}
```

My Javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my.aspx/getwidgets",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
       // do stuff with returned data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`getwidgets` needs to be static

```
[WebMethod]
public static String getwidgets()
```

Comment: When I change it to static, I get this error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WidgetWebsite._Default.widgetsBLObject'

Comment: I don't know what widgetsBLObject is, but if you have to use it then it needs to be static too.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if you want your method to be exposed to calls from JavaScript, you need to mark your method  with ScriptMethodAttribute. Thus making it look like this:

```
[ScriptMethod]
[WebMethod]
public static String getwidgets()
{
   // Your core here
}
```

I would return in the method, the object itself and not not a serialized version of it because ASP.NET will JSON serialize it for you if you mark it as [ScriptMethod]; so in the client your variable data.d will contain the object itself and not a simple string that later you have to deserialize, as in your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing technologies: my.aspx is for rendering HTML content, but it can be used to implement REST functionality.

In your case, the easiest would be to implement your code as part of the Page_Loaded() method. Make sure you clear the response first (so you don't have any additional markup in the response). Furthermore, you might want to set the content type of your response to JSON (rather than the default html):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        DataSet results = new DataSet();
        results = widgetsBLObject.selectTheWidgets();

        string jsresults = MyClassLibrary.JqueryTools.GetJSONString(results.Tables[0]);
        return jsresults;
    }
```

Then retrieve you JSON string at my.aspx (no getwidgets).

Also, since you are not posting any data, consider using GET rather than POST in your AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry Philipp, you lost me. I am not sure what you mean by 'set the content type of your response to JSON'. I simply already have a JSON string and need to retrieve it in ajax

Comment: No problem - i'll update my answer with some sample code shortly.